# What is the answer to the squirrel's second question in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I really need to know the answer to the second question from the Squirrel.

"That's right! Here's
20 candies for you.
Now complete this
sequence of letters
and you'll get a new
reward : S, E, I, D,
         N, A, ?"

Answer (score 2):

I typed in random letters and got it, but looking at it now, I think it was C...

The sequence spells Candies backwards.